# Is my evaluation of $\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}\delta_{ik}\delta_{nm}\delta_{mp}\delta_{np}$ correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

In this question we are using the Einstein Summation Convention, and $\delta_{rs}$ denotes the Kronecker-delta. We note that since $\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}\delta_{ik}=\delta_{ij}\delta_{ji}=\delta_{ii}=3$, and, similarly, $\delta_{mn}\delta_{mp}\delta_{np}=\delta_{mn}\delta_{nm}=\delta_{mm}=3$, we have that
$$
\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}\delta_{ik}\delta_{nm}\delta_{mp}\delta_{np}=3\cdot3=9
$$
The Einstein Summation convention is a very new concept to me, and questions along these lines are difficult to track down on Google. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Its correct (both the result and the argument). The first three terms have indices that are independent of the latter three so it factors as $(\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}\delta_{ik})\cdot (\delta_{nm}\delta_{mp}\delta_{np})$ and each of these two terms are identical (just different names for the dummy indices) so you get $3^2 = 9$.

Answer (score 1):

This looks good to me (assuming you're working in 3 dimensions)! As a double-check, you can equivalently think of this expression in terms of matrices as follows:
$$ (\delta_{ij} \delta_{jk} \delta_{ki}) (\delta_{nm} \delta_{mp} \delta_{pn}) = \operatorname{trace}(I\cdot I\cdot I) \cdot \operatorname{trace}(I\cdot I\cdot I) = 3 \cdot 3 = 9 $$
Here $I$ denotes the $3 \times 3$ identity matrix.